# How can I create an iOS CAAnimation and define every interpolated value myself?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, caanimation

I want to animate the path of a `CAShapeLayer`. However, this path is created using many arcs. The number of arcs is the same in the begin and end value of the path. However, since the arcs are of different length, this seems to mean that the actual paths use a different amount of Bezier Control Points. This means that the animation is not predictable and very glitchy*.

My solution so far is to create a `CAKeyFrameAnimation`, and put in a very high number of keyframes. It only works with a very high number of keyframes per second. (around 200 to 300). Anything lower, and glitches* start to appear.

This approach is very crude as it succes depends on the actual frame rate on the actual device and creates more instances of the key frames than is actually needed for the animation, wasting memory.
So my question is: Is there a way to create an animation where I have to create every value somehow? I am immagining some delegate based approach where I am asked a value based on a key time. I don't know what the best approach is to my problem.

***Note**: The glitches I am speaking of are weirdly looking paths that appear for one frame only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try using a `CADisplayLink`

Here is an example:

```
func setupAnimation() {
    let dispLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(updateAnimation))
    dispLink.preferredFramesPerSecond = 60 //will update 60 times per second (the default for iOS devices) ... this line of code is optional depending on the fps you want for your animation
    dispLink.add(to: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.common)
}

func updateAnimation() {
    //do your animation code here
}
```

Using a display link will link your animation to the refresh rate of the screen that way it's smooth and you can basically do anything you want without it looking choppy

Answer (score 2):

`UIBezierPath`, and it's underlying Core Foundation class, `CGPath`, do indeed use variable numbers of control points when creating an arc depending on the angle of the arc.

Thus, as you've discovered, if you're trying to animate a path that includes arcs with different angles, you get very strange drawing artifacts as the number of control points in the path changes.

I suggest using Catmull-Rom splines to create your arcs instead. A Catmull-Rom spline is a different kind of cubic curve where all the control points are on the curve. I learned about Catmull-Rom splines from the outstanding iOS Developers' Cookbook series by Erica Sadun (highly recommended reading.)

If you create a Catmull-Rom spline with about 10 points evenly spaced around a circle, the resulting curve you get will very closely approximate a circle. (I initially recommended 8 control points, but I just tried it, and a curve that describes a full circle doesn't look perfectly round until you have at least 10 control points.) If you want to generate a CGPath that contains an arc with a smaller angle, generate 10 control points that cover less or more of your arc.

I have a project on Github called [TrochoidDemo](https://github.com/DuncanMC/TrochoidDemo) that uses Catmull Rom Splines to create realistic looking water waves. You can ignore most of it, but it includes a file SmoothCGPointsArray.swift that will take an array of control points and use Catmull-Rom splines to return a new array with intermediate points that describe a smooth curve between your control points.

The function you want in that file is `smoothPointsInArray(_:granularity:adjustGranularity:)`

The `adjustGranularity` parameter defaults to true. That parameter tells the function to vary the number of smoothing points it creates depending on the distance between control points. You will want to override the default value and call the function with `adjustGranularity=false`, since for animation you always want the same number of points.

You would just call that function with an array of control points that includes 10 points for each arc you want to draw, regardless of angle. It would return an array of CGPoints, and you would then use the resulting array of `GCPoints` to generate a UIBezierPath using `lineTo()` commands, and then feed the `CGPath` from your `UIBezierPath` to your animation.

In your source array of points, if you want a given point to be a sharp corner, add that point twice in a row. If you want a line segment, add both endpoints of the line segment twice.

Here is what an 8-point approximation of a circle looks like: [image: 8-point Catmull-Rom circle]

And here is what a 10-point approximation of a circle looks like:
[image: 10-point Catmull-Rom circle]

(In each image above the Catmull-Rom approximation is drawn in black, with the control points shown in   blue, where the Cocoa-drawn circle is drawn in blue. Note that Cocoa uses Bezier curves to create it's circles, so Cocoa circles are also approximations.)